# freebsd-update failure

Tags: upgrade, freebsd

Some time ago, I upgrade my FreeBSD box to 7.1-RC2, but now I'd like to move to 7.2-RELEASE. I tried running

```
# uname -mrsi
FreeBSD 7.1-RC2 i386 GENERIC
# freebsd-update upgrade -r 7.2-RELEASE
Looking up update.FreeBSD.org mirrors... 3 mirrors found.
Fetching metadata signature for 7.1-RC2 from update4.FreeBSD.org... failed.
Fetching metadata signature for 7.1-RC2 from update5.FreeBSD.org... failed.
Fetching metadata signature for 7.1-RC2 from update2.FreeBSD.org... failed.
No mirrors remaining, giving up.
```

Substituting 7.1 for 7.2 gives the same error. Adding a `--debug` option shows the failure as being

```
fetch: http://update4.FreeBSD.org/7.1-RC2/i386/latest.ssl: Not Found
```

Is there any way to still do a binary upgrade of this system as the 7.1-RC* directories don't exist on http://update.freebsd.org anymore? Upgrading from source is an option, but I wanted to see if there was some way to salvage this installation.

Comment: Is there some reason a source upgrade is not an option for you?  I don't think there's a graceful way for you to do a binary upgrade at this point.

Comment: Bummer. Go ahead and propose this as a solution. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

from the [freebsd-update](http://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=freebsd-update&apropos=0&sektion=0&manpath=FreeBSD+7.1-RELEASE&format=html) manpage of 7.1:

```
 Note that updates are only available if they are being built for the FreeBSD 
 release and architecture being used; in particular, the FreeBSD Security Team
 only builds updates for releases shipped in binary form by the FreeBSD Release 
 Engineering Team, e.g., FreeBSD 6.1-RELEASE and FreeBSD 6.2-RC1, but not 
 FreeBSD 6.2-STABLE or FreeBSD 7.0-CURRENT.
```

it seems the answer is "no".